# Audit question, testing my understanding

Tags: discussion, review-audit

So,  I'm honestly curious if I'm misreading the intention of the site or not.  This came up in my close queue:  [Finite cover for $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188525/finite-cover-for-0-1)
I voted to close since it seemed to be in the style of a homework question with no research/thoughts from the poster,  just a "solve this for me" type.  I was told by the system that no, this was a perfectly fine question and I failed an audit.

Am I wrong?   Am I right?   Could this be seen either way?

Comment: If you look at the other things tagged [review-audit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audit) you'll see that you're not at all alone. The moral of the story is that you shouldn't worry too much about what review audits think, as long as you're being thoughtful in your reviews (and since you have justification for why you voted the way you did, I think you are)